# Angular how to get route id at resolve block?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can i get "pageid" inside resolve block?

For every url change i had to request the server, along with the "pageid"?

My code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/mainpage/:pageid',
          {
            controller:'ContentController',
                resolve: {
                  data: function ($q, $http) {
                        console.log(window.location.hash)

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({method: 'GET', url: mainURL}).then(function(data) {
                      deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                  }
                },                  
                 templateUrl : 'app/partials/masterTemplate.html'
          })
     .otherwise({redirectTo:'/mainpage/home'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
data: function ($http, $routeParams) {
    return $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: mainURL,
               params: {
                   pageid: $routeParams.pageid
               }
           })
           .then(function(data) {
               return data;
           });
}
```

Comment: solved this using $route, as   var pageID = $route.current.params.pageid;